# Bootstrap 3 search in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

so the bootstrap theme located here: http://www.bootply.com/render/129806
Is a really nice example. Now, please keep in mind that I do know HTML and CSS, I'm just a bit overwhelmed with this example (and bootstrap) and will pay it forward with help in the future.

But could somebody please explain the following:

1. How/where do I add form tags etc to make this search actually do a get request.
2. What's the best way of styling the search so it's not so long.
3. How would I add a Account drop down to the righter most side of this nav. I've tried pull-right, but after a few days of multiple edits, I'm over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this should help get you started with this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rpdgqnkc/

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-3">
      <form class="navbar-form" id="theSearchForm" name="theSearchForm" role="search" method="get" action="yoursearchfilescriptgoeshere">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:document.theSearchForm.submit();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>

    </div>
    </div>

  </form>
  </div>
```

1. Notice the form tag using the method="get" you would place whatever search script you have in the action and then use the href on the button to submit. You will need your own search script or if you are using google for a site search you can copy the code here https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1737334?hl=en
2. Wrap the search form in a div and control the sizing using the col-lg, col-md and col-sm. You will have to adjust font size, padding etc. with media queries on your nav to not have it break at certain widths dependent upon how many navigational elements you try to fit within the navbar.
3. Look to the fiddle for an example of a dropdown to the right.

Good luck with the rest of it

Comment: Thank you so much! I will jsfiddle my end result as an example for others.

Comment: Could you please show an example of how to make a category option (working) next to the search bar like in the example. Maybe even with a scroll bar in case the list is too large. Cheers

Comment: Sorry @KaneBright I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking, but will try to help if you can clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Here's what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/5kwgxswf/1/ But I want to make the arrow infront of my search box work and pass on a parameter? Would I just use <select>? Or would I need to do something funny with them in <li> tags? And should I set the list to a certain height and set the overflow to scroll to keep the size small?

Comment: And how could I make my search bar slightly larger too. Properly without breaking stuff. Only a little bigger

Comment: To make the categories be accepted as parameters in your search bar is a whole other question, search for ? # 23053442 and look at the comment links for a good starting point. Too make the search bar larger change the values for the col-lg, col-md etc. Good luck with the rest. . .